# How to create a database in oracle and its url?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle10g

I was using MySQL for my application. And i was using hibernate in my spring mvc application.

So all the tables are automatically created in my databse `(MyApp)`.

I wrote a command

`create database Myapp`

in Mysql command prompt.

And when i ran my application, all the tables were created automatically inside `Myapp`.

In my hibernate config file , to connect to Mysql i have used the following url

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Myapp
```

But now i want to change my database client to Oracle.

But i have seen in oracle the URL is given as

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
```

So the database is not mentioned in the URL?

And also the command i wrote to create database in Mysql is not working in oracle.

How i can do this?

Comment: oracle has another url format description **jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=localhost)(protocal=tcp)(port=1521))(connect_data=(service_name=Myapp)))**

Comment: @namxee How to create the database?

Answer (score 0):

Following table lists down popular JDBC driver names and database URL.

```
RDBMS   JDBC driver name                   URL format

MySQL   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver                  jdbc:mysql://hostname/ databaseName
ORACLE  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver        jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:portNumber:databaseName
DB2    COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.net.DB2Driver         jdbc:db2:hostname:port Number/databaseName
Sybase  com.sybase.jdbc.SybDriver              jdbc:sybase:Tds:hostname: port Number/databaseNam
```

Answer (score 0):

> So the database is not mentioned in the URL?

It is mentioned. In your example `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe`, `**xe**` is the database service name similar to `Myapp` in your `MySQL` example.

Answer (score -1):

Try to read the following links below

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0112.html

and download the drivers here and i think it contains some examples for you

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

and for creating the database please watch this tutorial video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZQ9ihJYRyM